Notification for document set properties only, not content
I have a SharePoint site with some content types defined. These content types inherit from Document Set and include some columns like text, dates, etc... They are used in libraries.
I would like the users able to set alerts to be notified when elements in these libraries are added, modified, deleted, etc... but only for columns, not for the contents. I mean I want users to receive notifications if somebody changes let's say a date column, but not if somebody modifies a document inside the document set.
I didn't find a way to do this.
Does somebody have an idea?
Thank you!
Oliver

You could create a flow as below.

